# How to disconnect Postgrex connection?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, postgrex

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a postgres database, run a query, and then disconnect.

Looking at [Postgrex](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex), I establish a connection using

```
{:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(hostname: "localhost", username: "postgres", password: "postgres", database: "postgres")
```

Then I execute my query using

```
Postgrex.query!(pid, "SELECT user_id, text FROM comments", [])
```

But then, how do I disconnect?

I'd like to disconnect because I am looping through N databases and running the same query on all of them.

I tried exiting the Process e.g. `Process.exit(pid, :bye)`, but it kills the spawning process also because it's started with `start_link/3`. I can't find a `start/3` function in `Postgrex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the `pid` returned by `Postgrex.start_link` is a `GenServer`, you can use `GenServer.stop/1`:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(hostname: "localhost", username: "postgres", password: "postgres", database: "postgres")
{:ok, #PID<0.277.0>}
iex(2)> GenServer.stop(pid)                                                                                                 
:ok
iex(3)> GenServer.stop(pid)
** (exit) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:797: :proc_lib.stop/3
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any danger of relying on implementation details of postgrex this way?

Comment: Based on the doc, it uses a `DBConnection` which itself uses a `GenServer`. So it is safe to say that the doc implies that it uses a `GenServer` and thus renders the usage of the `GenServer.stop/1` call safe.